# All plan generator plans in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

While reading [Oracle SQL tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/toc.htm) I came across such a quote (you can find it in this [chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optcncpt.htm#TGSQL192)):

> The **plan generator** explores various plans for a query block by trying out different access paths, join methods, and join orders.
>
> Many plans are possible because of the various combinations that the database can use to produce the same result. The optimizer picks the plan with the lowest cost.
>
> **Figure 4-2 Optimizer Components**
>
> [image: Figure 4-2 Optimizer Components]

Is it possible somehow to get **all** these plans that were generated by plan generator?

Maybe there are standard PL/SQL packages for this or system views?

Comment: No its not possible to get the intermediate plans generated whiling execution of a SQL in Oracle.

Comment: @XING Ok, thx. Maybe post it as an answer? I'll accept your answer then.

Comment: check the [10053](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjX8vzRmMreAhUDa8AKHakAAhoQFjAEegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.centrexcc.com%2FA%2520Look%2520under%2520the%2520Hood%2520of%2520CBO%2520-%2520the%252010053%2520Event.pdf&usg=AOvVaw34I7Con5a1sxKp8fUoraBR) trace if you want to lear internals about query optimization. You can see there some of the alternatives that were thrown away

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thx for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you do not need to see **all possible plans**, but in some cases there is an interesting question, why does Oracle discard some plan and use an alternative one instead.

To answer this the ideal entry is the **10053 trace** produced by Oracle.

There is a *classical paper* on this thema from Wolfgang Breitling which can be found [here](http://www.centrexcc.com/A%20Look%20under%20the%20Hood%20of%20CBO%20-%20the%2010053%20Event.pdf).

Also Jonathan Lewis in his [Cost-Base Oracle Fundamentals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596366) dedicated a chapter 14 *The 10053 Trace* to this thema.

Google will for sure provide other references.

A word of warning. The 10053 is not the simplest stuff in Oracle context. Also in each release you may expect changes in the output. A good starting point to learn is to investigate a query that produces a different execution plan in two different environments. Simple take the 10053 trace in both databases and make a file diff and observe the difference. You will see, if there is a difference in the optimizer parameters, object or system statistics and how those changes have influence on the selection of the final execution plan.